# How find this function $f(1+xy)=f(x)f(y)+f(x+y)$

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

let $f:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$,and for any real numbers $x,y$ have
$$f(1+xy)-f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$$
and $f(-1)\neq 0$.

Find the $f(x)$

My try:let $x=y=0$,then we have
$$f(1)-f(0)=[f(0)]^2$$

let
$$x=1,y=-1,\Longrightarrow f(0)-f(0)=f(1)f(-1)$$
since $f(-1)\neq 0$,
so 
$$f(1)=0$$
so
$f(0)=0 $ or $f(0)=-1$

Then I dont know what to do.

**Edit:** This is from IMO2012 Shortlist, Problem A5.

Comment: If $f(0)$ were $0$, then for $(x,y)=(0,-1)$ one would get $0-f(-1)=0$, contradicting $f(-1)\neq0$. So you can exclude that possibility.

Comment: Thank you,Thank you, Then ?

Comment: Well $f(x)=x-1$ works, but I don't know how to prove it is unique.

Comment: I don't know; is the fact that there is a unique (nonzero) ring homomorphism $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ related?

Comment: @DanShved: You are right, I will remove the comment. Still, I think it is unlikely such a functional equation would have a unique solution.

Comment: Somehow this whole business reminds reminds me of the theorem: if a bijection from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to itself preserves zero and straight lines, then it is linear. I suspect that $f(x) = x-1$ is the only solution, and the proof is similar to that theorem.

Comment: @Jonas Hm, now I suspect that it does. The theorem I mentioned in my comment above can be boiled down to this fact too.

Comment: Using $(x,y)=(-1,2)$ one finds that $f(2)=1$. Other possibly interesting fact: as a functional equation on just the integers, there is a "rogue solution" $n\mapsto(n\bmod3)-1$.

Comment: Official solution for this IMO shortlist problem can be found here: https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2012SL.pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I pick up where Marc van Leeuwen has stopped. If we put 
$g(x)=f(x+1)$, his answer has shown the following fundamental properties :

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
g(x)=x \ \text{when } x\in {\mathbb Z}, & (1) \\
g(2x)=2g(x) \ \text{when } x\in {\mathbb R} & (2) \\
g(-x)=-g(x) \ \text{when } x\in {\mathbb R} & (3) \\ 
g(x-1)+g(x+1)=2g(x) \ \text{when } x,y\in {\mathbb R} & (4) \\
g(xy)-g(x+y-1)=g(x-1)g(y-1) \ \text{when } x,y\in {\mathbb R} & (5) \\
\end{array}
$$

I will deduce from those properties that 
$$
g(ux+v)=ug(x)+v(g(x+1)-g(x)) (\ \text{when }  
x\in {\mathbb R},u,v\in{\mathbb Q},u\neq 0) \tag{6}
$$
Clearly, it suffices to show (6) when both $u$ and $v$ are integers. 
Thanks to (3), we may further assume that $u > 0$. We do this by induction
on $u$.

**Initial step :** (i.e. $u=1$) : this follows easily from (4) alone.

**Recurrence step :** Suppose that the property is true for all $u' \leq u$. Using
(5) with $y=u+1$, we deduce $g((u+1)x)=g(x+u)+g(x-1)g(u)$.
Now $g(u)=u$ by (1), and $g(x+u)=g(x)+u(g(x+1)-g(x))$ and 
$g(x-1)=2g(x)-g(x+1)$ by (4). So
$$
g((u+1)x)=g(x)+u(g(x+1)-g(x))+(2g(x)-g(x+1))u=(u+1)g(x) \tag{7}
$$
Let us now define the auxiliary function $h(v)=g((u+1)x+v)-(u+1)g(x)-v(g(x+1)-g(x))$ for $v\in{\mathbb Z}$. By (4), $h$ is harmonic over $\mathbb Z$. But by (7) above, $h$ is zero on all multiples of $u+1$. So $h$ is zero everywhere, and we have just finished the proof
of (6).

Let $t$ be any number. If we put $a=g(t)$ and $b=g(t+1)-g(t)$, then using (5) twice, first with $x=y=t$, second with $x=2t,y=2t$, we see that

$$
g(t^2)=2a-b+(a-b)^2 \ g(4t^2)=4a-b+(2a-b)^2 \tag{8}
$$

But we know that $g(4t^2)=4g(t^2)$ by (2). So we must have $4(2a-b+(a-b)^2)=4a-b+(2a-b)^2$, i.e. $(b-1)(4a-3b)=0$. Since there is more than
one possible value for $a$ ($a$ can be any integer), this forces $b=1$. We have just shown :
$$
g(x+1)-g(x)=1 (\ \text{when }  
x\in {\mathbb R}) \tag{9}
$$

So that (6) becomes 
$$
g(ux+v)=ug(x)+v (\ \text{when }  
x\in {\mathbb R},u,v\in{\mathbb Q}) \tag{6'}
$$

Combining (6') with (5) (used with $x=y$), we have 
$$
g(x^2)=g(x)^2, (\ \text{when }  
x\in {\mathbb R}) \tag{10}
$$

So $g$ is positive on ${\mathbb R}_{+}$. This positivity, together with (6'), implies
 that $g$ is nondecreasing. Since $g$ is the identity on ${\mathbb Q}$, it must be the 
 identity everywhere.

Comment: Ah, I see it now; so it's indeed increasing. Very nice.

Answer (score 7):

This question is very tough, and I give only a partial solution. It shows that for the restriction to $\def\Z{\Bbb Z}\Z[\frac12]=\{\,\frac n{2^k}\mid n\in\Z, k\in\Bbb N\,\}$, which is a dense subset of $\def\R{\Bbb R}\R$, there are precisely two solutions. Beyond this subring one solution clearly extends in a continuous way, but might also have other discontinuous extensions; the other (discontinuous) solution may or may not have extensions (**edit** the comment by DejanGovc shows that it does not extend). To settle the question of uniqueness of the only obvious solution $f:x\mapsto x-1$ (which was indicated by Jonas Meyer) appears to require new ideas that I have not found.

In view of that solution, it will be convenient to reason in terms of the translation $g:\R\to\R$ of$~f$ given by $g:x\mapsto f(x+1)$. The equation then becomes
$$
  g(xy)-g(x+y-1)=g(x-1)g(y-1) \qquad\text{for all $x,y\in\R$.} \tag 1
$$
Put $c=g(-2)$, which value is given to be nonzero. Let $z\in\R$; applying $(1)$ with $(x,y)=(-1,z+1)$ gives $g(-z-1)-g(z-1)=cg(z)$ and applying it again but with $(x,y)=(-1,1-z)$ gives $g(z-1)-g(-z-1)=cg(-z)$, and adding these two up and dividing by $c$ gives (replacing the name $z$ by $x$)
$$
  g(-x)=-g(x)  \qquad\text{for all $x\in\R$.} \tag 2
$$
It is then clear that $g(0)=0$, and putting $y=0$ in $(1)$ gives $g(x-1)(g(-1)+1)=0$ for all$~x$, which since $g(-2)\neq0$ implies $g(-1)=-1$. Now from $(2)$ also $g(1)=1$.

The instances of $(1)$ where $x$ or $y$ is in $\{0,1\}$ now provide no further information. For $y=2$ one gets
$$
  g(2x)=g(x-1)+g(x+1) \qquad\text{for all $x\in\R$,} \tag 3
$$
and for $y=-1$ one gets, using $(2)$, the "recurrence relation"
$$
  g(x-2)+cg(x-1)+g(x)=0 \qquad\text{for all $x\in\R$.} \tag 4
$$
Substituting $x+1$ for $x$ in$~(4)$ and subtracting this from $(3)$ gives
$$
  g(2x)=-cg(x) \qquad\text{for all $x\in\R$.} \tag 5
$$

One has $g(2)=-c$ from$~(2)$, then $g(3)=c^2-1$ from$~(4)$, and $g(4)=c^2$ from $(3)$ (or $(5)$) with $x=2$. But $(4)$ for $x=4$ gives $0=-c+c^3-c+c^2=c(c-1)(c+2)$, so since $c\neq0$ one must have $c=1$ or $c=-2$.

In both cases we can deduce unique solutions restricted to the ring $\def\Z{\Bbb Z}\Z[\frac12]$ by first solving $(4)$ to find the values $g(n)$ for $n\in\Z$, and then repeatedly applying $(5)$ to go halves. For $c=-2$ we get for $g$ the identity function on $\Z[\frac12]$. For $c=1$, combining two instances of $(4)$ gives $g(x)=g(x-3)$ so the values on $\Z$ are given by $g(n)=g(n\bmod 3)\in\{0,1,-1\}$, and we find for $n\in\Z$ and $k\in\Bbb N$:
$$
  g(\frac n{2^k})=(-1)^k r(n) \qquad\text{where }
  r(n)=(r+1)\bmod 3-1 =
 \begin{cases}1&\text{if $n\equiv1\pmod3$},\\
              0&\text{if $n\equiv0\pmod3$},\\
              -1&\text{if $n\equiv-1\pmod3$.}\\
 \end{cases}
$$
Since $r(-n)=-r(n)$ and $2^k\equiv(-1)^k\pmod3$ it is easy to see that this definition is consistent across various way of expressing the same fraction, and to see that it indeed gives a solution if$~(1)$ restricted to $\Z[\frac12]$, one may choose $k,l$ even (to avoid multiple cases), for which the desired equation
$$
  g(\frac n{2^k}\frac m{2^l}) - g(\frac n{2^k}+\frac m{2^l}-1) = g(\frac n{2^k}-1)g(\frac m{2^l})
$$
reduces to
$$
  r(nm)-r(2^ln+2^km-2^{k+l})=r(n-2^k)r(m-2^l)
$$
and since $r$ has period $3$ this becomes
$$
  r(nm)-r(n+m-1) = r(n-1)r(m-1)
$$
which can be checked to hold for all combinations of classes in $\Z/3\Z$.

If one would like to prove that the identity is the only solution on$~\R$ for $g$, one might want to establish that $g$ is increasing, or (which would imply this) that $g(x)>0$ for $x>0$, but I don't see how one can derive such things from the given functional equation.

Comment: Beautiful! Here's an observation: the "rogue solution" cannot be extended to $\mathbb R$. To see this, let $y=3$ in $(1)$. We get $g(3x)=g(x+2)+g(2)g(x-1)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. But, since $g(x)=g(x-3)$ in this case, this implies that $g(3x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @DejanGovc: Thank you for that complement, you are quite right. I though first that this kind of argument could not give any contradiction, because they would also apply _inside_ $\Bbb Z[\frac12]$. But indeed $g(3x)=0$ does hold for all $x\in\Bbb Z[\frac12]$, it just doesn't imply that $g=0$ there. So your argument shows one cannot even extend the $c=1$ case to $\frac13\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I've managed to complete Marc van Leeuwen's solution (i.e. uniqueness of the solution in the case $c=-2$.) The following argument should prove that $g(x)>0$ for $x>0$. (Which is sufficent, according to Marc van Leeuwen; Ewan Delanoy has also provided a nice argument for this fact in his answer.)

I would like to emphasize that Marc van Leeuwen deserves the credit for the solution. This is really just an extended comment to his answer. The numbers of the form $(n)$ (where $n\in\mathbb N$) refer to equations in his answer.

Here's the argument: letting $y=-x$ in $(1)$ we obtain $$g(-x^2) - g(-1) = g(x-1)g(-x-1).$$ Using $(2)$ and $g(-1)=-1$, this becomes $$g(x^2) - 1 = g(x-1)g(x+1). \tag{I}$$ Letting $y=1-x$ in $(1)$, we obtain $$g(x(1-x)) - g(0) = g(x-1)g(-x).$$ Using $(2)$ and $g(0)=0$, we obtain $$g(x(x-1))=g(x)g(x-1).\tag{II}$$ Multiplying this last equation by $4$ and using $(5)$, we obtain that $$g(2x(2x-2)) = g(2x)g(2x-2).$$ Substituting $x=\frac{z+1}2$ into this, we get $$g((z+1)(z-1))=g(z+1)g(z-1).$$ Comparing this with $(\mathrm I)$ yields $$g(x^2)-1=g(x^2-1).$$ This means that for $z\geq 0$, $$g(z)-1=g(z-1)\tag{III}$$ holds. Using $(2)$ again we can see that $(\mathrm{III})$ holds for all $z\in\mathbb R$, since for $z\leq1$ we have $$g(z-1) = -g(1-z)=-(g(1-z)-1+1)=-(g(-z)+1)=g(z)-1.$$ Using $(2)$ on this in a different way, we get $$g(z+1)=-g(-z-1)=-(g(-z)-1)=g(z)+1\tag{IV}$$ Applying $(\mathrm{III})$ and $(\mathrm{IV})$ to $(\mathrm I)$, we see that $$g(x^2)-1=(g(x)-1)(g(x)+1)=g(x)^2-1.$$ Therefore $g(x^2) = g(x)^2$ holds for all $x\in\mathbb R$, which implies that $g(x)>0$ holds for all $x>0$.

Comment: Oops, I didn’t see your solution before posting mine. In my solution, I prove first that $g$ is $\mathbb Q$-linear, then the positivity of $g$ implies that it is nondecreasing.

Answer (score 0):

try to find solution in this form :

f(x)=x²+ax+b

if we put y=-x in equation we get

f(1-x²)-f(x-x)=f(x)f(-x)

so f(1-x²)=-1+f(x)f(-x)

so (1-2x²+x^4)+a(1-x²)+b=-1+(x²+ax+b)(x²-ax+b)

this need to be true for all x so

-a-2=2b-a², a+b+1=b²-1

so a=b²-b-2=(b+1)(b-2)

also a(a-1)=2(b+1)

so (b+1)(b-2)(b²-b-3)=2(b+1)

so one solution is b=-1,a=0 so f(x)=x²-1 is solution

other is maybe when b³-3b²-b+4=0

i.e. if we put b-1=t we have t³-4t+1=0

solutions are t1~-2.1149 ,t2~0.25410 , t3~1.8608

then a=(b+1)(b-2)=(t+2)(t-1)

but a must be 0,so these 3 solutions aren't our solutions

just f(x)=x²+1

if we assume f(x)=x+c

then 1-x²+c=-1+(x+c)(c-x)

so 1+c=-1+c²

i.e. c²-c-2=0 i.e. (c+1)(c-2)=0

so c=-1 or c=2

but when we check we see f(x)=x-1 is solution,

so f(x)=x-1 or f(x)=x²-1

also we can prove that f(x)=x^n-1 isn't solution for n>2,n natural number

that means that these two are the only two polynomial with positive integer degrees that satisfy.